# SQL query returns no records

Tags: php

This query doesn't return value actually have value in `database` .
 Red colour identify problem of query . Table is related other foreign table .
 actually sylhet value have in database `where` clause does not work properly .

`select * from chamber where chamber_district = 'Sylhet'`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the table

Comment: my table are https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul3kG.png

Comment: Don't post code as images. Copy/paste the code into the question itself.

Comment: Check 2 points- 1. Is this query returning data when you run this in mysql console. 2. Check for blank space in data column of chamber_district.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can  solve this problem . when I take input below query **chamber_district** column take extra space by  **' $district'**  variable input query. this extra space cannot shown by eye in database.

Correct query :

```
 $sql = "insert into chamber(doctor_id , chamber_district, area, consultation_center,additional_note, new_fee, returning_fee, report_fee ) values ( '$doctor_id' , '$district', '$area', '$consultation_center', '$additional_note', '$new_patient', '$return_patient' , '$report');"
```

previous wrong query

```
$sql = "insert into chamber(doctor_id , chamber_district, area, consultation_center,additional_note, new_fee, returning_fee, report_fee ) values ( '$doctor_id' , '  $district  ', ' $area ', '$consultation_center', '$additional_note', '$new_patient', '$return_patient' , '$report');"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your database value for chamer_district is "sylhet sadar" and you comparing only "Sylhet" and that's why it not return the data. If you want to compare only "Sylhet" then you have to use "like" operator and your query is something like this:

```
select * from chamber where chamber_district like 'Sylhet%'
```

Comment: I want use equal operator for data search form data base.

Comment: @AshrafulAlam, If you want to use equal operator then you have to compare whole value

Comment: I want compare by equal operator my  database table chamber_district column value  is "Sylhet "

Comment: my table link are https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul3kG.png                                                                    and code link are https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrjIA.png

Comment: According to the OP's screen dump, the value of `chamber_district` is actually just `Sylhet`. It's the column `area` that contains `sylhet sadar` (which is not the column the OP is checking)

Comment: @AshrafulAlam, Sorry I checked the wrong column "area" for the value.